# How to stop statistics DB endless growth

Tags: sql-server

We have Microsoft SQL Server 2012 database used for storing statistics data from the queueing system. Queueing system is sending statistics to DB every 10 minutes and database size is growing around 1 GB per week.

We do not need data older than 1 year.

We have created a SQL script to delete old data. After the script is executed, DB size is bigger.

```
use statdb

-- Execute as stat user
-- The following three settings are used to control what will be used

-- Amount of days of stat data which should be kept
DECLARE @numberOfDaysToKeep int=365

-- If set to 1, also the aggregated data will be removed, otherwise only the events will be removed
DECLARE @DeleteAggregateData int = 1

-- If set to 1, also the hardware monitoring data will be removed.
DECLARE @DeleteAgentDcData int = 1

-- Do not change anything below this line
DECLARE @DeleteBeforeDate int = (SELECT id FROM stat.dim_date WHERE full_date > DATEADD(day,-1-@numberOfDaysToKeep,GETDATE()) AND full_date < DATEADD(day,0-@numberOfDaysToKeep,GETDATE()))

-- Remove CFM events
DELETE FROM stat.fact_visit_events where date_key < @DeleteBeforeDate
DELETE FROM stat.fact_sp_events where date_key < @DeleteBeforeDate
DELETE FROM stat.fact_staff_events where date_key < @DeleteBeforeDate

-- ...continue to delete from other tables
```

We would like to keep DB size on constant size. Does MS SQL server use free space (after delete) or will DB size grow at the same speed as before delete?

Or do I need to run SHRINK after script? (based on other discussions, it is not recommended)

Comment: `Does MS SQL server use free space (after delete)?` Yes

Comment: Are your tables heaps or do they have clustered indexes?

Comment: Hi Vladimir, thank you for your response. So for example:
- DB size is now 76 GB
- after delete, it has size 98 GB
- new data will be stored in the database, but it will not take new space from the operating system. The file size will stay the same 98 GB. Even if before it grown 1 GB per week.

Is that true?

Comment: @MartinStarosta, yes, in my experience this is how it works. The DB size stabilises. In our system we also regularly rebuild indexes after deleting old data. This rebuilding of indexes defragments them and keeps statistics up to date. All our tables have clustered index, i.e. there are no heaps. I'm not sure if heaps have some special behaviour.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov, yes, heaps have special behaviors on deletion, that caused my question

Comment: @VladimirBaranov When I rebuild indexes, the file size of DB grown even more. I am not sure, how can I check if we have heap or clustered indexes. The database is installed on a virtual server.

Comment: @MartinStarosta, yes, rebuilding indexes needs space, because engine is essentially storing the second copy of data while rebuild. But then it will start reusing this space on the second rebuild. You just need to try yourself on a scaled down example. You don't need to have a full blown 100GB database for it. Create a test database with a couple of tables only few GB in size and start adding and deleting tons of rows. You will quickly see how file size changes.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov too late :-D I am just now deleting old data (so far 6 hours execution) :-)

Answer (score 0):

You do not provide information is your database is in FULL recovery mode or SIMPLE recovery mode. For sure you have to shrink your log file as well as a data file. In SSMS you can see how much free space is available for the data file and for the log file. See the image below.

[image]

There is an option to shrink the data file and the log file using T-SQL. 
See more on [DBCC SHRINKFILE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-shrinkfile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Database is in FULL mode. Based on discussions I thought that SHRINK is not recommended because of performance issues. I did delete and shrinking only LOG file, database size has decreased. Is this a correct process?

Comment: Yes. If your database still grows you should consider shrinking data file as well. This task should be accomplishing at weekends. As I showed SSMS has a nice feature to show you how much free space might be released.

Comment: @DarkoMartinovic [Stop Shrinking Your Database Files. Seriously. Now.](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/08/stop-shrinking-your-database-files-seriously-now/)

Comment: Yes, I agree. That is the rule. But there are exceptions to. That the reason why the appropriate commands to shrink exists. As I understand this post is about exceptions.